# Class method for adding custom provider to Faker

Tags: python, class-method, faker

I am using the [Python Faker API](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) and I want add a custom provider to it. I want register my custom provider with the class Faker and not the instance. As I read [here](https://github.com/joke2k/faker#how-to-create-a-provider), it seems we can register the custom provider only with the instance. I am trying to build a wrapper over the API and it would help if I can register it with the class rather than the instance.

Is there a way to do so? Any help is appreciated.